# Evenly distribution of data in vector

Tags: c++, vector

I want to distribute a vector of 52 numbers evenly in other two vectors. Such that each respective vector will have 26 values taken randomly from a primary vector. i.e in this case it is storein

**code**

```
vector<int>p1;
vector<int>p2;

for(int i=0;i<=storein.size();i++)  //storein has a size of 52
{
int a=rand()%storein.size()+1;
int b=rand()%storein.size()+1;
if(a!=0)
{
cout<<"First player draw"<<endl;
p1.push_back(a);
cout<<p1[i]<<endl;
}

if(b!=0)
{
cout<<"Second player draw"<<endl;
p2.push_back(b);
cout<<p2[i]<<endl;
}
}

cout<<"p1 "<<p1.size()<<" p2 "<<p2.size()<<endl;
```

Comment: Can you modify the original vector? If so, shuffle it, then copy the first half into one vector and the second into another.

Comment: The C++ [standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) have many nice [algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) in it, for example to [partition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) a range based on a predicate. The library also have nice [pseudo-random](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) functionality that includes classes to give you a [range of numbers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) (like zero or one, for false and true). All of this can of course be combined.

Comment: if i do that it will give repetitive values on each run.original vector has value of 52 cards.

Comment: It will? How do you know that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just shuffle your input vector and then put the first 26 entries in `p1` and the last in `p2`:

```
std::mt19937 rd{std::random_device{}()};
std::shuffle(input_vec.begin(),input_vec.end(),rd);

std::vector<int> p1 {input_vec.begin(),input_vec.begin()+26};
std::vector<int> p2 {input_vec.begin()+26, input_vec.end()};
```

If you don't want to change `input_vec`, just make a copy.

Note that this way of seeding the mt19937 is potentially not quite optimal as its state space is quite a bigger than the 32 bit seed. This won't matter for toy programs and your standard programming assignment, but for completeness sake: [Here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/109260/seed-stdmt19937-from-stdrandom-device) is my take on properly seeding the whole state space.

As a last remark: Do not use `rand()`, [it is bad.](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful)